# Why is my tikz-figure rendered flushed to the right off-centre?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Here is the code for my graphical model:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style  ={draw,minimum width=2.5em, shape=circle,thick, black,fill=white},
  visiblenode/.style ={draw, minimum width=2.5em, shape=circle,thick, black,fill=black!20},
  plate/.style={draw,
                shape=rectangle, 
                thick, 
                minimum width=4em,
                minimum height=4em, 
                align=right, 
                inner sep=5em, 
                inner ysep=5em,
                label={[xshift=-16pt,yshift=11pt]south east:#1}}
}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,thick,node distance=5em]
    % NODES
    \node[latentnode] (z0) {$\mathbf{x}_1$};
    \node[latentnode, right of=z0] (z1) {$\mathbf{x}_2$};
    \node[latentnode, right of=z1] (z2) {$\mathbf{x}_3$};
    \node[draw=none,,right= 1.5em of z2] (zdots) {$\cdots$};
    \node[latentnode,right= 1.5em of zdots] (zN) {$\mathbf{x}_T$};

    % hyperparameter
    \node[latentnode,left of = z0] (pi) {$\boldsymbol \pi_k$};
    \node[plate=$\infty$, inner sep=5pt, fit=(pi)] (plate1) {};
    \node[draw=none,left of = pi] (alpha) {$\alpha$};
    \node[draw=none,left of = pi, above=0.6em of pi] (kap) {$\kappa$};
    \node[latentnode,above of = pi] (b) {$\boldsymbol \beta$};
    \node[draw=none,left of = b] (g) {$\gamma$};

    \node[visiblenode,below of=z0] (x0) {$\mathbf{y}_1$};
    \node[visiblenode,below of=z1] (x1) {$\mathbf{y}_2$};
    \node[visiblenode, right of=x1] (x2) {$\mathbf{y}_3$};
    \node[draw=none,right= 1.5em of x2] (xdots) {$\cdots$};
    \node[visiblenode,right= 1.5em of xdots] (xN) {$\mathbf{y}_T$};

    % hyperparameters
    \node[latentnode,left of =x0] (t) {$\boldsymbol \theta_k$};
    \node[plate=$\infty$, inner sep=5pt, fit=(t)] (plate1) {};
    \node[draw=none,left of = t] (lam) {$\boldsymbol \lambda$};

    % PATHS
    % horizontal
    \path [line] (z0) -- (z1);
    \path [line] (z1) -- (z2);

    % vertical
    \path [line] (z0) -- (x0);
    \path [line] (z1) -- (x1);
    \path [line] (z2) -- (x2);
    \path [line] (zN) -- (xN);

    % connect dots
    \path [line] (z2) -- (zdots);
    \path [line] (zdots) -- (zN);

    %hyperparameter
    \path [line] (lam) -- (t);    
    \path [line] (alpha) -- (pi);
    \path [line] (b) -- (pi);
    \path [line] (g) -- (b);
    \path [line] (kap) -- (pi);

    \path [line] (pi) -- (z0);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (z1.135);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (z2.135);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (zN.135);
    % \path [line] (pi.0) -- (zN.140);

    \path [line] (t.0) -- (x0);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (x1.225);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (x2.225);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (xN.225);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This comes out as so:

[image: Off-centre graphical model.]

As you can see the whole image sits off-centre and there are parts of the right-most nodes missing.

Why is the model not being rendered completely centered?

Comment: Sorry but what's missing?

Comment: It is centred. But you have positive inner separation for the label nodes (by default and/or as configured) which are not drawn, so you don't see the boundaries. In contrast, those on the right are drawn, so the inner separation is part of the content within the node boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is centred but the nodes on the far left are not drawn, so their `inner sep` is not obviously part of a node, whereas those on the right are drawn, so their `inner sep` appears as part of the content within the node boundaries. To see this, just change `draw=none` to `draw=red` for the leftmost nodes.

[image: centred]

As can be seen, the leftmost sides of the leftmost nodes are bang up against the boundary of the picture, just as they are for the rightmost points on the boundaries of the rightmost nodes. (Not all the far left nodes are right up to the picture boundary because the nodes vary in width, depending on their content, but the widest ones are up against the boundary.)

The space at the bottom is probably due to invisible points used in constructing the curved paths, though I'm not positive about this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style  ={draw,minimum width=2.5em, shape=circle,thick, black,fill=white},
  visiblenode/.style ={draw, minimum width=2.5em, shape=circle,thick, black,fill=black!20},
  plate/.style={draw,
    shape=rectangle,
    thick,
    minimum width=4em,
    minimum height=4em,
    align=right,
    inner sep=5em,
    inner ysep=5em,
    label={[xshift=-16pt,yshift=11pt]south east:#1}},
  line/.style={draw, -latex'}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,thick,node distance=5em]
    % NODES
    \node[latentnode] (z0) {$\mathbf{x}_1$};
    \node[latentnode, right of=z0] (z1) {$\mathbf{x}_2$};
    \node[latentnode, right of=z1] (z2) {$\mathbf{x}_3$};
    \node[draw=none,,right= 1.5em of z2] (zdots) {$\cdots$};
    \node[latentnode,right= 1.5em of zdots] (zN) {$\mathbf{x}_T$};

    % hyperparameter
    \node[latentnode,left of = z0] (pi) {$\boldsymbol \pi_k$};
    \node[plate=$\infty$, inner sep=5pt, fit=(pi)] (plate1) {};
    \node[draw=red,left of = pi] (alpha) {$\alpha$};
    \node[draw=red,left of = pi, above=0.6em of pi] (kap) {$\kappa$};
    \node[latentnode,above of = pi] (b) {$\boldsymbol \beta$};
    \node[draw=red,left of = b] (g) {$\gamma$};

    \node[visiblenode,below of=z0] (x0) {$\mathbf{y}_1$};
    \node[visiblenode,below of=z1] (x1) {$\mathbf{y}_2$};
    \node[visiblenode, right of=x1] (x2) {$\mathbf{y}_3$};
    \node[draw=none,right= 1.5em of x2] (xdots) {$\cdots$};
    \node[visiblenode,right= 1.5em of xdots] (xN) {$\mathbf{y}_T$};

    % hyperparameters
    \node[latentnode,left of =x0] (t) {$\boldsymbol \theta_k$};
    \node[plate=$\infty$, inner sep=5pt, fit=(t)] (plate1) {};
    \node[draw=red,left of = t] (lam) {$\boldsymbol \lambda$};

    % PATHS
    % horizontal
    \path [line] (z0) -- (z1);
    \path [line] (z1) -- (z2);

    % vertical
    \path [line] (z0) -- (x0);
    \path [line] (z1) -- (x1);
    \path [line] (z2) -- (x2);
    \path [line] (zN) -- (xN);

    % connect dots
    \path [line] (z2) -- (zdots);
    \path [line] (zdots) -- (zN);

    %hyperparameter
    \path [line] (lam) -- (t);
    \path [line] (alpha) -- (pi);
    \path [line] (b) -- (pi);
    \path [line] (g) -- (b);
    \path [line] (kap) -- (pi);

    \path [line] (pi) -- (z0);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (z1.135);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (z2.135);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (zN.135);
    % \path [line] (pi.0) -- (zN.140);

    \path [line] (t.0) -- (x0);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (x1.225);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (x2.225);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (xN.225);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

As [Ignasi mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285779/why-is-my-tikz-figure-rendered-flushed-to-the-right-off-centre/285784?noredirect=1#comment690366_285784), `inner sep` or `inner xsep` can be zeroed for the relevant nodes. For example, we could use the following style for these nodes:

```
  jump left/.style={draw=none, inner xsep=0pt},
```

But this will affect the right side as well as the left, as [Ignasi said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285779/why-is-my-tikz-figure-rendered-flushed-to-the-right-off-centre/285784?noredirect=1#comment690366_285784), so you'd need to compensate for this. For example, we could define a modified version of the `line` style for these lines.

```
  jump line/.style={line, shorten <=5pt}
```

Making these changes produces the following result.

[image: jump styles]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
  latentnode/.style  ={draw,minimum width=2.5em, shape=circle,thick, black,fill=white},
  visiblenode/.style ={draw, minimum width=2.5em, shape=circle,thick, black,fill=black!20},
  plate/.style={draw,
    shape=rectangle,
    thick,
    minimum width=4em,
    minimum height=4em,
    align=right,
    inner sep=5em,
    inner ysep=5em,
    label={[xshift=-16pt,yshift=11pt]south east:#1}},
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
  jump left/.style={draw=none, inner xsep=0pt},
  jump line/.style={line, shorten <=5pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,thick,node distance=5em]
    % NODES
    \node[latentnode] (z0) {$\mathbf{x}_1$};
    \node[latentnode, right of=z0] (z1) {$\mathbf{x}_2$};
    \node[latentnode, right of=z1] (z2) {$\mathbf{x}_3$};
    \node[draw=none,,right= 1.5em of z2] (zdots) {$\cdots$};
    \node[latentnode,right= 1.5em of zdots] (zN) {$\mathbf{x}_T$};

    % hyperparameter
    \node[latentnode,left of = z0] (pi) {$\boldsymbol \pi_k$};
    \node[plate=$\infty$, inner sep=5pt, fit=(pi)] (plate1) {};
    \node[jump left, left of = pi] (alpha) {$\alpha$};
    \node[jump left, left of = pi, above=0.6em of pi] (kap) {$\kappa$};
    \node[latentnode,above of = pi] (b) {$\boldsymbol \beta$};
    \node[jump left, left of = b] (g) {$\gamma$};

    \node[visiblenode,below of=z0] (x0) {$\mathbf{y}_1$};
    \node[visiblenode,below of=z1] (x1) {$\mathbf{y}_2$};
    \node[visiblenode, right of=x1] (x2) {$\mathbf{y}_3$};
    \node[draw=none,right= 1.5em of x2] (xdots) {$\cdots$};
    \node[visiblenode,right= 1.5em of xdots] (xN) {$\mathbf{y}_T$};

    % hyperparameters
    \node[latentnode,left of =x0] (t) {$\boldsymbol \theta_k$};
    \node[plate=$\infty$, inner sep=5pt, fit=(t)] (plate1) {};
    \node[jump left, left of = t] (lam) {$\boldsymbol \lambda$};

    % PATHS
    % horizontal
    \path [line] (z0) -- (z1);
    \path [line] (z1) -- (z2);

    % vertical
    \path [line] (z0) -- (x0);
    \path [line] (z1) -- (x1);
    \path [line] (z2) -- (x2);
    \path [line] (zN) -- (xN);

    % connect dots
    \path [line] (z2) -- (zdots);
    \path [line] (zdots) -- (zN);

    %hyperparameter
    \path [jump line] (lam) -- (t);
    \path [jump line] (alpha) -- (pi);
    \path [line] (b) -- (pi);
    \path [jump line] (g) -- (b);
    \path [jump line] (kap) -- (pi);

    \path [line] (pi) -- (z0);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (z1.135);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (z2.135);
    \path [line] (pi.35) to [bend left=20] (zN.135);
    % \path [line] (pi.0) -- (zN.140);

    \path [line] (t.0) -- (x0);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (x1.225);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (x2.225);
    \path [line] (t.325) to [bend right=20] (xN.225);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh I see, very good answer. Do you know if there is any way in which one set the inner-sep to zero for some nodes, on the left side only, and then use that class for just those four hyperparameters (i.e. the nodes on the left)?

Comment: @Astrid: You can use `inner {x|y}sep=0pt` as option for left hand nodes but this suppresses all space around them. If you want to keep some white space at right hand side, you can force it with a `\phantom` space inside node's text. Something like `\node[draw=red,left of = b, inner xsep=0pt] (g) {$\gamma\phantom{\,}$};`

Comment: @Astrid Please see edited answer for one method. [Ignasi](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285779/why-is-my-tikz-figure-rendered-flushed-to-the-right-off-centre/285784?noredirect=1#comment690366_285784) suggested another.

Comment: @cfr: Nice! Your solution is far more elegant than mine.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you. I'm not sure it is better or more elegant. It is just more familiar/natural to me personally. I tried to draw from e.g. `([xshift=5pt]g)` but that didn't work so I used this instead. But this is arguably better since it uses a style so could be easily changed *en masse* so to speak.